# Sorting a flattened object

Tags: javascript, sorting, object

I currently have a object and i wanted to flatten it, the code below does the following;

**EDIT:**

Just updated the structure to contain the priority as well.

```js
var input = {
    "a11/a22/animations": {
        "title": "title here",
        "priority": 2
    },
    "a11/a22/colours": {
        "title": "title here",
        "priority": 1
    },
    "a11/a22/fonts": {
        "title": "title here",
        "priority": 3
    },
    "a11/a22/visibility": {
        "title": "title here",
        "priority": 4
    },
    "a11/b22/logo": {
        "title": "title here",
        "priority": 1
    },
    "a11/c22/define": {
        "title": "title here",
        "priority": 2
    },
    "a11/c22/ordered": {
        "title": "title here",
        "priority": 3
    },
    "a11/c22/unordered": {
        "title": "title here",
        "priority": 1
    },
    "a11/d22/foot": {
        "title": "title here",
        "priority": 2
    },
    "a11/d22/head": {
        "title": "title here",
        "priority": 1
    },
    "a11/e22/blockquote": {
        "title": "title here",
        "priority": 2
    },
    "a11/e22/headings": {
        "title": "title here",
        "priority": 1
    },
    "a11/e22/hr": {
        "title": "title here",
        "priority": 4
    },
    "a11/e22/inline-elements": {
        "title": "title here",
        "priority": 3
    },
    "a11/e22/paragraph": {
        "title": "title here",
        "priority": 6
    },
    "a11/e22/preformatted": {
        "title": "title here",
        "priority": 5
    },
    "a11/e22/time": {
        "title": "title here",
        "priority": 7
    },
    "b11/f22/menu": {
        "title": "title here",
        "priority": 1
    },
    "b11/g22/product-item": {
        "title": "title here",
        "priority": 1
    },
    "b11/h22/search": {
        "title": "title here",
        "priority": 1
    },
    "b11/i22/sub-menu": {
        "title": "title here",
        "priority": 1
    },
    "c11/j22/footer": {
        "title": "title here",
        "priority": 1
    },
    "c11/j22/title": {
        "title": "title here",
        "priority": 2
    },
    "c11/k22/header": {
        "title": "title here",
        "priority": 1
    }
  },
  output = {};

Object.entries(input).forEach(
  ([k, v]) =>
    (k.split("/").reduce((o, k) => (o[k] = o[k] || {}), output).value = v)
);

console.log(output);

console.log(output);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

This flattens out the entire process. However, in the `json` structure under value, i have a value called `priority` with an integer. I want to be able to sort the by the `priority` at the second level. `a22` and `c22`, it should sort `define`, `ordered` and `ordered` based on the priority underneath it.

```
.sort((a, b) => input[a].priority - input[b].priority)
```

**Expected Results**:

```
{
  "a11": {
    "a22": {
      "colours": {
        "value": {
          "title": "title here",
          "priority": 1
        }
      },        
      "animations": {
        "value": {
          "title": "title here",
          "priority": 2
        }
      },
      "fonts": {
        "value": {
          "title": "title here",
          "priority": 3
        }
      },
      "visibility": {
        "value": {
          "title": "title here",
          "priority": 4
        }
      }
    },
    "b22": {
      "logo": {
        "value": {
          "title": "title here",
          "priority": 1
        }
      }
    },
    "c22": {
      "unordered": {
        "value": {
          "title": "title here",
          "priority": 1
        }
      },        
      "define": {
        "value": {
          "title": "title here",
          "priority": 2
        }
      },
      "ordered": {
        "value": {
          "title": "title here",
          "priority": 3
        }
      },
    },
    "d22": {
      "head": {
        "value": {
          "title": "title here",
          "priority": 1
        }
      },        
      "foot": {
        "value": {
          "title": "title here",
          "priority": 2
        }
      },
    },
    "e22": {
      "headings": {
        "value": {
          "title": "title here",
          "priority": 1
        }
      },        
      "blockquote": {
        "value": {
          "title": "title here",
          "priority": 2
        }
      },
      "inline-elements": {
        "value": {
          "title": "title here",
          "priority": 3
        }
      },      
      "hr": {
        "value": {
          "title": "title here",
          "priority": 4
        }
      },
      "preformatted": {
        "value": {
          "title": "title here",
          "priority": 5
        }
      },      
      "paragraph": {
        "value": {
          "title": "title here",
          "priority": 6
        }
      },
      "time": {
        "value": {
          "title": "title here",
          "priority": 7
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "b11": {
    "f22": {
      "menu": {
        "value": {
          "title": "title here",
          "priority": 1
        }
      }
    },
    "g22": {
      "product-item": {
        "value": {
          "title": "title here",
          "priority": 1
        }
      }
    },
    "h22": {
      "search": {
        "value": {
          "title": "title here",
          "priority": 1
        }
      }
    },
    "i22": {
      "sub-menu": {
        "value": {
          "title": "title here",
          "priority": 1
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "c11": {
    "j22": {
      "footer": {
        "value": {
          "title": "title here",
          "priority": 1
        }
      },
      "title": {
        "value": {
          "title": "title here",
          "priority": 2
        }
      }
    },
    "k22": {
      "header": {
        "value": {
          "title": "title here",
          "priority": 1
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What are you talking about? What do you mean by sorting "an object"? You can only sort arrays, not single objects.

Comment: please add what you like to sort and the result after sorting.

Comment: @NinaScholz - i have just updated the structure above.

Comment: shouldn't it be `.sort((a, b) => a.priority - b.priority)`?

Comment: @Ebuall but where should it be placed? as its flattening first.

Comment: please add the wanted result as well.

Comment: @NinaScholz just added expected results as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could sort the entries before you generate a new object by taking `priority` and sort the items ascending.

```js
var input = { "a11/a22/animations": { title: "title here", priority: 2 }, "a11/a22/colours": { title: "title here", priority: 1 }, "a11/a22/fonts": { title: "title here", priority: 3 }, "a11/a22/visibility": { title: "title here", priority: 4 }, "a11/b22/logo": { title: "title here", priority: 1 }, "a11/c22/define": { title: "title here", priority: 2 }, "a11/c22/ordered": { title: "title here", priority: 3 }, "a11/c22/unordered": { title: "title here", priority: 1 }, "a11/d22/foot": { title: "title here", priority: 2 }, "a11/d22/head": { title: "title here", priority: 1 }, "a11/e22/blockquote": { title: "title here", priority: 2 }, "a11/e22/headings": { title: "title here", priority: 1 }, "a11/e22/hr": { title: "title here", priority: 4 }, "a11/e22/inline-elements": { title: "title here", priority: 3 }, "a11/e22/paragraph": { title: "title here", priority: 6 }, "a11/e22/preformatted": { title: "title here", priority: 5 }, "a11/e22/time": { title: "title here", priority: 7 }, "b11/f22/menu": { title: "title here", priority: 1 }, "b11/g22/product-item": { title: "title here", priority: 1 }, "b11/h22/search": { title: "title here", priority: 1 }, "b11/i22/sub-menu": { title: "title here", priority: 1 }, "c11/j22/footer": { title: "title here", priority: 1 }, "c11/j22/title": { title: "title here", priority: 2 }, "c11/k22/header": { title: "title here", priority: 1 } },
    output = {};

Object
    .entries(input)
    .sort(({ 1: { priority: a } }, { 1: { priority: b } }) => a - b)
    .forEach(([k, v]) => (k.split("/").reduce((o, k) => (o[k] = o[k] || {}), output).value = v)
);

console.log(output);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```